# Python 2 function to python 3 convertion

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have got the following function from an old project and getting this error

> def haversine_distance((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)): ^ SyntaxError:
> invalid syntax

```
def haversine_distance((lat1, lon1), (lat2, lon2)):
    """
    Haversine distance between two points, given by lon and lat in degrees.
    """

    d_lat = radians(lat2 - lat1)
    d_lon = radians(lon2 - lon1)

    a = sin(d_lat / 2.0) ** 2 + \
        cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * \
        sin(d_lon / 2.0) ** 2

    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    return R * c
```

I would love to know to convert this to python 3.8 best practices. help

Answer (score 3):

Define your function as `haversine_distance(p1, p2)` in Python3 and unpack lat, lon in function body. For example:

```
def haversine_distance(p1, p2):
    """
    Haversine distance between two points, given by lon and lat in degrees.
    """
    lat1, lon1 = p1
    lat2, lon2 = p2

    d_lat = radians(lat2 - lat1)
    d_lon = radians(lon2 - lon1)

    a = sin(d_lat / 2.0) ** 2 + \
        cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) * \
        sin(d_lon / 2.0) ** 2

    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    return R * c
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @AndrejKesely answer and for more readable code I would define a namedtuple `Point` with `lat` and `lon` fields. and then work with them

```
from collections import namedtuple
from math import radians, sin, cos, atan2, sqrt

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'lat, lon')

def haversine_distance(point1, point2):
    """
    Haversine distance between two points, given by lon and lat in degrees.
    """

    d_lat = radians(point2.lat - point1.lat)
    d_lon = radians(point2.lon - point1.lon)
    a = sin(d_lat / 2.0) ** 2 + cos(radians(point1.lat)) * cos(radians(point2.lat)) * sin(d_lon / 2.0) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

    return R * c # assuming R is global constant 

point1 = Point(42, 23)
point2 = Point(41, 23)
print(haversine_distance(point1, point2))
```